# Unpermitted parameters: author

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My requirements 
Basically I'm adding books to a database, and I want to store the Author in a separate table. So I have a table called authors which is referenced by the table books.

I want to create a rails form for adding a book, and I'd like it to be just a simple form for Author, Title, Publisher etc, and if it finds the author already in the authors table then it should just reference that record, and if it isn't in the authors table then it should add a new record and reference it.

while storing values i am getting  in log file 
Unpermitted parameters: author

```
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8sxeOVMVJucl5nN+kMpSaT1cB1yDPnk5gfKElWPiT5k=", "book"=>{"book_name"=>"life ", "price"=>"20", "author"=>{"author_name"=>"swamy", "title"=>"LIFE", "publisher"=>"cta"}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}

swamy
LIFE
cta
  Author Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors"  WHERE "authors"."author_name" = 'swamy' AND "authors"."title" = 'LIFE' AND "authors"."publisher" = 'cta' LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (25.2ms)  INSERT INTO "authors" ("author_name", "created_at", "publisher", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["author_name", "swamy"], ["created_at", "2015-07-01 03:53:22.712401"], ["publisher", "cta"], ["title", "LIFE"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-01 03:53:22.712401"]]
   (16.8ms)  COMMIT
Unpermitted parameters: author
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("Author_id", "book_name", "created_at", "price", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["Author_id", 8], ["book_name", "life "], ["created_at", "2015-07-01 03:53:22.865106"], ["price", 20], ["updated_at", "2015-07-01 03:53:22.865106"]]
   (22.4ms)  COMMIT
```

my code
books_Controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end
 def create

  @a=params[:author_name]
  puts @a
  b=params[:book][:author][:author_name]
  puts b
#   @c = @b.authors
#   @d = @c.author_name
   c=params[:book][:author][:title]
        d=params[:book][:author][:publisher]

  puts c
   puts d
   @author = Author.find_or_create_by(author_name: b,title: c, publisher: d)
   @book = Book.new(books_params)
   @book.Author = @author  
   @book.save 
  redirect_to root_url

 end
private

  def books_params
     params.require(:book).permit(:book_name, :price,:author_attributes => [:author_name, :title, :publisher])
end 
end
```

model

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Author
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :Author
 # def author_name=(author_name)
  #  self.author = Author.find_or_create_by_name author_name
  #end
end
```

view
books.html.erb

```
<%= form_for Book.new  do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :book_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :book_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :author do |b| %>
     <p>
    <%= b.label :author_name%><br />
    <%= b.text_field :author_name %>
  </p>
<p>
    <%= b.label :title%><br />
    <%= b.text_field :title %>
  </p>
<p>
    <%= b.label :publisher%><br />
    <%= b.text_field :publisher%>
  </p>

  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
~
```

Hi sir i am new to rails i know it looks simple but i unable it find solution

~
~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is full of errors. Follow my changes.

```
#book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
end

#books_controller.rb
def new
@book = Book.new
@book.build_author
end

def create
@book = Book.new(books_params)
 if @book.save 
   redirect_to root_url
 end
end
```

Finally in your ***form*** change `<%= form_for Book.new  do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for @book  do |f| %>`

Comment: Thank you sir,but only book values are stored in database but author table have nil value ,can u please explain how to  store data to author table after checking author already existing or not

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `books_params` has `author_attributes` when it should be `author` based on your parameters.

This should work:

```
def books_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:book_name, :price, :author => [:author_name, :title, :publisher])
end
```

Comment: thank you for response but i edited above code but i am getting unknown attribute: author error in line @book = Book.new(books_params)

Answer (score 0):

Change `authore` to `author_attributes` in view file, like this.

```
 <%= f.fields_for :author_attributes do |b| %>
  <p>
   <%= b.label :author_name%><br />
   <%= b.text_field :author_name %>
  </p>
```

Also change respectively in controller also. I think, this much is enough.

```
def create
  @book = Book.new(books_params) 
  @book.save 
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will Suggested you just `debug` your code

```
def books_params
byebug
  params.require(:book).permit(:book_name, :price, :author => [:author_name, :title, :publisher])
end
```

**1:**  check your **requested params**

**2:**  kindly check `params.require(:book)`

Requested parameter would be like

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8sxeOVMVJucl5nN+kMpSaT1cB1yDPnk5gfKElWPiT5k=", "book"=>{"book_name"=>"life ", "price"=>"20", "author_"=>{"author_name"=>"swamy", "title"=>"LIFE", "publisher"=>"cta"}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

[check with this link NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Your controller would be this

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @author = Author.create(params[:book])
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

  def books_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:book_name, :price,:author_attributes => [:author_name, :title, :publisher])
  end
end
```